# how can I crawl comments with specific id value with xpath

Tags: ruby, xpath, web-crawler

Here, I'm using xpath to crawl certain page of amazon. 
Here, the code of the page looks like below (part)

```
<div id="cm-cr-dp-review-list" data-hook="top-customer-reviews-widget" class="a-section review-views celwidget">
  <div id="R3FBEIWJLE4KEI" data-hook="review" class="a-section review">
  <div id="R1G0...." >
```

since the reviews are consist of title and body parts, I wrote `ruby` script like this.

```
    r = Nokogiri::HTML(revised_content)
    reviews = r.xpath("//div[@class='a-section review-views celwidget']").map.with_index do |review, _ii|
    binding.pry
    {
        title: make_japanese(review.xpath("//a[@data-hook='review-title']/text()").to_s),
        content: make_japanese(review.xpath("//div[@data-hook='review-collapsed']/text()").to_s)
    }
    end
```

However, this doesn't make mapped contents, rather `title` contained all the titles of comments. How can I effectively divide such structured DOM?

Comment: Start your XPath with `.` to make it relative to current context element : `review.xpath(".//a[@data-hook='....")`

Comment: well this doesn't work either